# do I have to call off on dom elements in the view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, marionette

If on my ''onRender'' I set an event handler on the dom element. Do I have to manually set an ''off'' on the view destroy?

```
onRender: ->
  @$('#my-element').on("something:happened"), -> 
     alert('test');

onDestroy: ->
  @$('#my-element').off("something:happened")
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the framework does it for you:

View implements a destroy method, which is called by the region
managers automatically. As part of the implementation, the following
are performed:

call an onBeforeDestroy event on the view, if one is provided

call an onDestroy event on the view, if one is provided

unbind all custom view events

**unbind all DOM events**

remove this.el from the DOM

unbind all listenTo events

returns the view.

http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.view.html#view-destroy